# nodejs same version number in all the dependencies

Tags: node.js, docker

During docker vulnerability check we found that package minimatch has vulnerabilities. Due to this we have to use minimatch package to latest which is 3.0.4.

I have copied the package-lock.json in the **js section** of fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/Loecjuy4/1/

```
"minimatch": "3.0.4" instead of  "minimatch": "2.0.10"
```

If you search the package-lock.json at fiddler link that I provided, you will find minimatch as dependencies in many places sometimes version 3.0.4 is used (line 2022 in eslint) while in other places version 2.0.10 is used (line 3170).

I want to know a way such that package minimatch has the same version 3.0.4 in all the places of package-lock.json. I have tried shrinkwrap but it too shows different version of minimatch.

Comment: You tagged your question with [docker] tag, could you please indicate the relevance? Also where did you get your `package-lock.json` from?

Comment: Remove the `package-lock.json` and regenerate it

Comment: Open an issue at the relevant repository of packages that use the outdated version as dependency, after you updated these packages to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Update all your dependencies to the latest version. If the old version is still in your `package-lock.json`, it means that the dependencies you use have a dependency itself on the old version. You should then probably contact the maintainers of these packages to upgrade their dependencies (i.e. by opening an issue on their respective repository).